# Java Override CompareTo method

Tags: java, coordinates, priority-queue, comparator

I have Coordinates class and I want to make Coordinates object comparable.

```
public class Coordinates implements Comparable<Coordinates> {

private int row;
private int column;
```

The idea is to insert Coordinates objects into PriorityQueue and to get them out sorted.

```
 @Override
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    if (row < o.row) {
        return row;
    }
    if (row > o.row) {
        return o.row;
    }
    if (row == o.row) {
        if (column < o.column) {
            return column;
        }
        if (column > o.column) {
            return o.column;
        }
    }
//    return 0;
}
```

This is my attempt but I am not sure what exactly am I expected to return and how to return it. I want my smallest coordinates to have highest priority. And the function I wrote still expects a return value - the commented line

Comment: Smallest in what sense? Like, how should `(1, 2)` compare to `(2, 1)`?

Comment: You can calculate distance from `(0, 0)` for each object and then use that to compare.

Comment: I want 0,5 to have highest priority than 1,5 and 1,0 to have higher priority than 1,3

Comment: compareTo should return -1 for greater, 0 for equal and +1 for less than. it doesn't matter how negative or positive the value is.

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually, it is 0 for equal, >0 for less, and <0 for greater

Comment: @ByeBye True, only the sign matters

Comment: I think that @JasonPer should tell us what he really wants to do here...

Comment: ppl are so clever here to down vote the fastest correct answer for the question!!!!

Comment: @hasan83 what makes you think your answer is correct?

Comment: Because it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want 0,5 to have highest priority than 1,5 and 1,0 to have higher priority than 1,3

In effect you want a reverse sort. However, a priority queue places the lowest values first so natural order make the lowest values to appear first.

You want to return <0 for less than and >0 for greater than

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    if (row < o.row) return -1;
    if (row > o.row) return +1;

    if (column < o.column) return -1;
    if (column > o.column) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

You can simplify this with `Integer.compare`

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    int cmp = Integer.compare(row, o.row);
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = Integer.compare(column, o.column);
    return cmp;
}
```

Note: if you assume row and column are non-negative you can write

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Coordinates o) {
    int cmp = row - o.row;
    if (cmp == 0)
        cmp = column - o.column;
    return cmp;
}
```

Comment: [Comments archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135053/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-lawrey-java-override-compareto-method).

Answer (score -2):

```
if (row < o.row) {
    return row;
}
else if (row > o.row) {
    return o.row;
}
else
{
    if(row == o.row)
    {

        if (column < o.column) {
            return column;
        }
        if (column > o.column) {
            return o.column;
       }
    }
}
```

Fix the if-else brach, hope you are getting the **return missing syntax error**

Comment: And the function I wrote still expects a return value - the commented line

Comment: I mean you must be kidding on that one then :)